# Django FastCGI and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, .htaccess, fastcgi

I tried to install Django with FastCGI but without success!. It gives me a 500 Error, but if I execute my ./dispatch.fcgi on shell it gives me the "it works!" HTML page of Django.

Here is my url http://mydjango.webmashing.com

and my dispatch.fcgi file is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/webmashi/.local/lib/python")
os.chdir("/home/webmashi/.local/lib/python/myproject")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "myproject.settings"
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

.htaccess file:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update my python version from 2.4 to 2.6 and it's worked :)

Comment: In my case, I started off with a user-installed 2.7.6. When I referenced 2.6 instead, it worked. My, something must be up, but I guess I'll stick with 2.6