# Django dispatch.fcgi Works From Command Line but gets 500 from Browser

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I have a Django app running on a shared server using FCGI.  When I run the dispatch.fcgi script from the command line, I see the HTML content of my homepage, as expected.  However, when I try to visit my homepage using my browser, I get a 500 error.  My question is basically the same as this one: [Django FastCGI and 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298434/django-fastcgi-and-500-internal-server-error) except that I am already on Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log the exception - put your entire dispatch.fcgi file in a try/except block and write the traceback to a file you can inspect:

```
from traceback import format_exc
try:
    # current dispatch.fcgi code
except Exception:
    open("/path/you/can/write/to.txt", "w").write(format_exc())
    raise
```

Hopefully that's enough to figure out the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me figure out that I needed to fix my django directory hierarchy in site-packages.  I then had an issue with mysterious unhandled Flup exceptions, which weren't logged using that code, but I found a solution here: http://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?id=1083.  Thanks again!